# Jenkins Shelving jobs using Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I'm currently writing a script that should archive all the jobs that has'nt been used for the last year, i couldn't find any command that should shelve those jobs.
Any idea how to do that ?
Here is my script:

```
import hudson.model.*


jobs = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items
Date date  =  new Date ()
currentTimeInMillis = date.getTime();
println "Today is "  + date + " In MilSec  " + currentTimeInMillis


def milSecondInSecond = 1000
def secondsInMinute = 60
def monutesInHour = 60
def secondsInHour = secondsInMinute*monutesInHour
def hoursInDay = 24
def minutesInDay = monutesInHour * hoursInDay
def secondsInDay = minutesInDay*secondsInMinute
def daysInYear = 365.242199
def hoursInYear = daysInYear*hoursInDay
def minutesInYear = hoursInYear*monutesInHour
def secondsInYear = minutesInYear*secondsInMinute
def milSecondsInYear = secondsInYear*milSecondInSecond
println "The milSeconds in year is  " + milSecondsInYear

for (job in jobs) {
    lastbuild = job.getLastBuild() 
    if (lastbuild !=  null) {
        lastbuildInMilSeconds = lastbuild.getTimeInMillis()
        def dif = currentTimeInMillis - lastbuildInMilSeconds
        if (dif > milSecondsInYear) {
            println job.getDisplayName() + "  " + lastbuild.getTimeInMillis()

        }
  }

}
```

Any idea which commands should i add, i know that there is a plugin for this, but i want to automate this proccess.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Install the [Shelve Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shelve+Project+Plugin) and have your Groovy code call ShelveProjectTask to do the actual shelving work

**Option 2:**

Read the code for the [Shelve Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shelve+Project+Plugin) and reproduce it in your script.

Option 1 sounds far easier and more reliable. You still get the benefits of automation. Plus the benefits of reuse.

Comment: How do i call `Shelve Project Plugin` from my code?

Comment: It is Java code. You import the package it uses and instantiate the ShelveProjectTask object. You'll need to do a little code reading to make sure you call the right method.

Comment: I haven't found the source of this plugin, there is any way you could send me it?